# remove corrupt csproj file and get copy off of a remote branch

Tags: git, csproj

I did a git pull and came across a bunch of these inside of my project .csproj file.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======

>>>>>>> 298a8db9b1cc88afda040414503dbc9d753cfd6a
```

It seems like it would be easiest to delete my file take that file off the remote branch.

How would I do this without affecting the commits that I have already made?

Comment: Did you already commit the file with the conflict markers, or did you just do the merge and have to resolve the file in the workspace now before commiting the merge?

Comment: i have not committed the current csproj file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a merge conflict and want to resolve it by using `ours` version or `theirs` version, just use `git checkout --ours .csproj` or `git checkout --theirs .csproj`.